# status code 404 when accessing ingress (nginx)

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, http-status-code-404, kubernetes-ingress

I have kibana running on a kubernetes cluster and wanted to expose kibana through the subpath `/kibana`. Here is my yaml configuration:

```
apiVersion: kibana.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Kibana
metadata:
  name: kb-qs
spec:
  version: 8.6.2
  count: 1
  elasticsearchRef:
    name: es-qs
  config:
    server:
      basePath: "/kibana"
      rewriteBasePath: true
      publicBaseUrl: "https://localhost:5601/kibana"
  http:      
    tls:
      selfSignedCertificate:
        disabled: true 
  podTemplate:
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: kibana
          readinessProbe:
            initialDelaySeconds: 210
            periodSeconds: 30
            httpGet:
              scheme: HTTP
              path: "/kibana/login"
              port: 5601
```

To expose kibana I also enabled nginx-ingress-controller and created this ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-kb
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules: 
  - host: ""
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /kibana(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: kb-qs-kb-http
            port:
              number: 5601
```

However, wenn I try to access the ingress via `http://localhost/kibana` it says 404 not found. I specified the subpath in my kibana config, the readiness probe and also my ingress. The kb-qs-kb-http service listens on port 5601. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this annotation then you could use `regex`.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
```

Comment: I already tried that, still getting 404 :/

Comment: Could you please add nginx access.log from nginx-ingress? There should be a deployment(e.g, ` ingress-nginx-controller` ) in a specific namespace(e.g, ` ingress-nginx-controller`)?

Comment: These are the most recent logs:

```I0403 08:42:50.120941       7 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"ingress-kb", UID:"c1e57c0c-587c-45d6-a9c7-041bab1eee4a", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"1647", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
10.244.0.1 - - [03/Apr/2023:08:43:27 +0000] "GET /kibana HTTP/1.1" 404 60 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0" 923 0.082 [default-kb-qs-kb-http-5601] [] 10.244.0.4:5601 60 0.082 404 950029ccc0b2871369327a462c73f0b6```